# Twilio browser remember the microphone permissions for WebRTC

Tags: javascript, twilio

When we are loading pages with http every thing work as expected each call browser asks to grant media permission after allowing permission twilio is making the calls. I am updating twilio capability token before each call through ajax.

```
...
Twilio.Device.setup(twilio_token)
...
```

Problem is when the pages are loading with https because to remember media permission as given in twilio documentation

https://www.twilio.com/help/faq/twilio-client/can-the-browser-remember-the-microphone-permissions-for-webrtc

1st time when allow media permission we can make a call, after that to make next calls, device setup is not updated with new token to make calls getting following error

```
Cannot initiate call. Invalid token
```

How to make the device ready with new token for next calls, when browser remembers the media permission. I am thing after media allow only twilio device is setup ready.

Answer (score 1):

You could try handle the following event that the Twilio js client provides.

```
Twilio.Device.offline(softPhoneOffline);

function softPhoneOffline(device)
{
   console.log("softPhoneOffline");
   // Called on network connection lost.
   refreshtoken(); //Refresh Token 
}

function refreshtoken()
{
  Twilio.Device.setup(); // Just a sample, you would provide setup with a generated token
}
```

Regards

Louis